# find the value of c that minimizes the sum of the areas of two regions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, area

> Let $f(x) = x^3-x^2$. For a given value of c, the graph of $f(x)$, together with the graph of the line $y=c+x$, split the plane up into regions. Suppose c is such that exactly two of these regions have finite area. Find the value of c that minimizes the sum of the areas of these two regions.

Note that $f(x) = (x-1/3)^3 - 1/3 (x-1/3)-2/27,$ which has 180 degree symmetry around the point $(1/3, -2/27)$. One can see this because a 180 degree rotation about $(0,0)$ sends $(x,y)$ to $(-x,-y)$, so rotating a point (x,y) 180 degrees about $(1/3, -2/27)$ is equivalent to rotating $(x-1/3, y+2/27)$ 180 degrees about (0,0) and then translating the result by the vector $(1/3, -2/27)$, which gives $(-x+2/3, -y-4/27)$. So if $y=(x-1/3)^3 - 1/3(x-1/3)-2/27$, then $(-x+1/3)^3 - 1/3(-x+1/3) - 2/27 = -y - 4/27,$ and hence the graph of $f$ is invariant under rotation about $(1/3, -2/27)$.

Suppose the graph of f cuts $y=c+x$ into two segments of lengths a and b.

> How can one determine with proof that the maximum sum of areas is achieved when $y=c+x$ passes through $P=(1/3, -2/27)$?

Comment: Do you want the minimum (up top) or the maximum (very end)?

Comment: Btw, here is an identical question with accepted answer https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4418331/1048496

Answer (score 2):

I think the picture is necessity in your question. Here red line is the one which is conjectured to be optimal and magenta one is an arbitrary differen line. The problem is to show that area dotted with blue is smaller than the area dotted with green.

The latter is equivalent to showing that the part of magenta line in the left region is shorter than the part in the right region. (To see this use the area representation as an integral over $du\,dv$ where $u = x + y$ and $v = x - y$.)
[image]

We want to show that the part of the magenta line in the left region is shorter than the part in the right region. Draw the image of the magenta segment after the symmetry with center at the intersection of the red line and the graph of $f$ with cyan. Then the aim is to show that cyan segment is shorter than the magenta one:[image]

Rotate the picture by 45 degrees so that the red line becomes the x-axis. Notice that the graph of $f$ after the rotation is still a plot of some function. Indeed, this is equivalent to the fact that every line of the form $x+y=c$ intersects the initial plot in a single point, which is true because on the whole line the inequality $f'>-1$ holds. Hence the picture after the rotation is somewhat like:
[image]

Where the new function is monotone in both regiones between the green tangents. Now the inequality for the segments evidently follows.

Comment: @Apass.Jack, thank you for suggestions and clarification. I've added the details

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha\lt \beta\lt\gamma$ be the roots of $x^3-x^2=x+c$.

Also, let $s:=\beta-\alpha$ and $t:=\gamma-\beta$.

Then, since $\beta=\alpha+s$ and $\gamma=\alpha+s+t$, we have
$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=1\iff \alpha=\frac{1-2s-t}{3}$$
$$\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha=-1\iff s^2 + s t + t^2 = 4\iff (s-t)^2=4-3st\ (\geqslant 0)$$

Squaring the both sides of $s^2 + s t + t^2 = 4$ gives
$$s^4 + 2 s^3 t  + 2 s t^3 + t^4=16-3(st)^2$$

Using these, the sum of the areas can be written as

$$\begin{align}&\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)dx+\int_{\beta}^{\gamma}\bigg(-(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)\bigg)dx
\\\\&=\frac{1}{12}(\alpha -\beta)^3 (\alpha + \beta - 2 \gamma)+\frac{1}{12}(\beta - \gamma)^3 (2\alpha - \beta - \gamma)
\\\\&=\frac{1}{12}s^3(s+2t)+\frac{1}{12}t^3(2s+t)
\\\\&=\frac{1}{12}(s^4 + 2 s^3 t + 2 s t^3 + t^4)
\\\\&=\frac{1}{12}(16-3(st)^2)
\\\\&\geqslant \frac{1}{12}\bigg(16-3\bigg(\frac 43\bigg)^2\bigg)\end{align}$$

The equality is attained only when $st=\frac 43$ iff $s=t$ iff $\beta-\alpha=\gamma-\beta$ iff $\beta=\frac 13$ iff $y=x+c$ passes through $P=(\frac 13, -\frac{2}{27})$ iff $c=-\frac{11}{27}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A(c)$ be the relevant area with respect to $c$.
Let $g_c(x)=x+c$.
By now you probably know that if (and only if) $c\in(-1,5/27)$, then the $f-g_c$ has exactly $3$ real roots,
which we will denote by $r_1(c)<r_2(c)<r_3(c)$.
These are functions of $c$ because they can be uniquely determined from $c$.
In fact, it is not hard to show that
$$
r_1(c)<-\frac{1}{3}<r_2(c)<1<r_3(c).
$$

By implicit function theorem, all $r_i$ are differentiable,
and
$$
r_i'(c)=\frac{1}{3r_i(c)^2-2r_i(c)-1}.
$$
It is easy to see that $r_i'(c)<0$ if and only if $r_i(c)\in(-1/3,1)$.
Thus, $r_1,r_3$ are strictly increasing, and $r_2$ is strictly decreasing.

Now we compute the derivative of $A$ with respect to $c$.
By Libneiz rule,
$$
\begin{align*}
A'=\frac{d}{dc} \left(\int_{r_1}^{r_2} f-g\ + \int_{r_2}^{r_3} g-f\right)
&= -(r_2-r_1) + r_3-r_2.
\end{align*}
$$
Note that $r_2-r_1$ is strictly decreasing, and $r_3-r_2$ is strictly increasing,
so $A'$ is strictly increasing.
At $c^*=-11/27$ (i.e. at the midpoint), we have $A'(c^*)=0$ (by the symmetry of the graph you have observed).
Since $A'$ is strictly increasing, $c^*$ must be the minimum point of $A$, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Hints towards a solution:

1. Show that the area is at an extrema when $a = b$.

   - For each $c$, let the left line segment have length $a(c)$, and the right line segment have length $b(c)$.
   - Treat the area as an integral of these line segments as $c$ varies. If $ a(c) > b(c)$, how can we minimize the area by adjusting $c$?
   - Note: This extrema need not be unique.
   - Show that $a(c)$ is a decreasing function and $b(c)$ is an increasing function, hence the extrema is unique, and is a minimum.
2. Thus, at the minimum $C$, we want $x^3 - x^2 = x + C$ to have roots of the form $m-n, m, m+n$.

   - Why does $ a(C)= b(C)$ mean that the roots of this equation are equal distance apart?
   - Using Vieta, show that $ (m-n) + m + (m+n) = 3m = 1$ and $(m-n)m + m(m+n) + (m+n)(m-n) = 3m^2 - n^2 = -1$
   - Hence, solve for $m, n$ and show that $ C = (m-n)m(m+n) = - \frac{11}{27}$.